# Getting an error with mapping when using MongoRepository findById

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

When I try to use the `findById` method from MongoRepository with a string passed in, I get an error with the mapper which leads to no results being returned, even though such exists.

**Here is my project's structure and files:**

**Entity** *Post.java*

```
@Document("posts")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {
    @Id
    private String Id;
    private Integer userId;
    private String content;
    private Integer likes;
    private Integer dislikes;
}
```

**Repository** *PostRepository.java*

```
public interface PostRepository extends MongoRepository<Post, String> {

}
```

**Service** *PostService.java*

```
@Service
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository repository;

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Post getPostById(String id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public Post savePost(Post post) {
        return repository.save(post);
    }

    public void deletePostById(String id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

**Controller** *PostController.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService service;

    @Autowired
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @GetMapping("")
    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return service.getPosts();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{postId}")
    public Post getPostById(@PathVariable String postId) {
        return service.getPostById(postId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/createPost")
    public Post createPost(@RequestBody Post post) {
        streamBridge.send("postCreated-out-0", post.getUserId());
        return service.savePost(post);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{postId}")
    public void deletePostById(@PathVariable String postId) {
        service.deletePostById(postId);
    }
}
```

When I try running either a `GET` such as `localhost:9192/posts/62a76719145e644e5b640327` or a DELETE `localhost:9192/posts/62a76719145e644e5b640327`, where `62a76719145e644e5b640327` is a correct id associated with a entry in the document in MongoDB I get this error in the console:

```
[nio-9192-exec-2] o.s.d.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper   : Could not map 'Post.id'. Maybe a fragment in 'String' is considered a simple type. Mapper continues with id.
```

I also tried writing a custom query using the `@Query` annotation that overwrites the default findById as such:

```
@Override
@Query("{ 'id' :  ?0}")
Optional<Post> findById(String s);
```

And I still get the same error. I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` version 2.7.0 and I am running MongoDB locally.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the same thing happens when using the `deleteById` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is in the identifier u named it with capital I
replace **Id** in posts document with **id** ?
give it a try... it will work

Comment: Yeah you were correct, the capitalization of the **Id** field was the reason for the error, changing it to **id** fixes the issue.